# Programatically fire action bar menu item in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, selection, android-actionmode, actionmode

I have actionbar with menu item on the bar. When I click on the refresh icon I have method that shows up the progress bar.

I would like to do the on loading of this activity. Hence, I tried calling the refresh icon item click programatically:

```
onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.action_Refresh));
```

I am calling the above after creating the menu.

But this gives null pointer exception on load my data. If I click on refresh button it is working fine, but if I call it programmatically I get an error.

Here is what I have:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    this.optionsMenu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.action_Refresh));

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case R.id.action_about:
        aboutapp();
        return true;

    case R.id.action_Refresh:
        Log.e("REfressh","Clicked");
        Mapsthree.refreshValue = 0;
        timer = new Timer();
        timerMethod();
        setRefreshActionButtonState(true);
        displayView(1);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void timerMethod()
{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            updateProgressBar();
        }

    }, 0, 800);
}

private void updateProgressBar() 
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            if (Maps.refreshValue == 1)
            {
                setRefreshActionButtonState(false);
                timer.purge();
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void setRefreshActionButtonState(final boolean refreshing) 
{
    if (optionsMenu != null) 
    {
        final MenuItem refreshItem = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.action_Refresh);
        if (refreshItem != null) 
        {
            if (refreshing) 
            {
                refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
            } 
            else 
            {
                refreshItem.setActionView(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call a menu item programmatically? if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap the code you execute for the refresh action in a new method, then call it for the action item and wherever you need it to be called in your activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you calling it from `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

You can write the code for loading in `onCreate` or `onResume` method depending on the requirement:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {

    super.onCreate(arg0);

    //whatever you are doing

    //now code for refresh

    Log.e("REfressh","First time");
    Mapsthree.refreshValue = 0;
    timer = new Timer();
    timerMethod();
    setRefreshActionButtonState(true);
    displayView(1);
}
```

Comment: I can't, I am changing the refresh icon to progressbar only when it is clicked.

Comment: So, you want it to be changed to progressbar on the first loading too?

Comment: That is right - because I loading few things from cloud and takes time.

Comment: Used your logic with few changes. Working fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Just do `findViewById(R.id.action_Refresh).callOnClick();`

or

`findViewById(R.id.action_Refresh).performClick();`

Comment: This required API 15... I am supporting app from API 14.

Comment: Well change it to performClick() instead.. Simple.

Comment: Well I can assure you that works. I just tried that. If you call that it will click the R.id.action_Refresh view. Unless it's disabled or something, the `onOptionsItemSelected` will get fired.

Comment: Oh... Are you just trying to click on a item of a menu that wasn't even created yet? The menu will only be able to click after onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: I am trying this inside: onCreateOptionsMenu, after creating the menu I am just calling: findViewById(R.id.action_Refresh).performClick();

Comment: "after creating the menu"? That's false. The menu is ONLY created after the return true. Until then there is no menu at all. Hence the NPE.

Comment: So where should I put it then?

Comment: First start by removing everything you have on your onOptionsItemSelected and try your initial solution. I bet that if you remove it and just put a toast there it will be called. The NPE are getting thrown because you are probably calling some function there that messes with the view somehow. View that has been not created yet.

Comment: I removed everything and just added log like what you suggested still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :
get the reference of the Menu class `opMenu` inside your Activity here:

```
Menu opMenu;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    opMenu= menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    onOptionsItemSelected(opMenu.findItem(R.id.action_Refresh));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);;
}
```

Use `opMenu.findItem()` to trigger click

Comment: @TheDevMan just replace your code with mine and check,you have used `menu.findItem()`, i am getting correct result.

Comment: I tried it with a method it worked but I am using micro.pravi logic. Works perfectly with the method. Thanks! Given a +1 for your logic thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// check is assignable to menu item implementation
if(menuItem !=null 
    && MenuItemImpl.class.isAssignableFrom(menuItem.getClass())){
  // if so cast 
  MenuItemImpl impl = (MenuItemImpl)menuItem;
  // invoke listener 
  impl.invoke();
}
```

which is equal to implementation;

```
public boolean invoke() {
    if (mClickListener != null && mClickListener.onMenuItemClick(this)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (mIntent != null) {
        mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

you can always use reflections :)